# Delete "windows Personals certificate" from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I try to remove certificate from command line:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w8SY.png)
i run this code but is not deleting

```
    C:\Users\A\Desktop>powershell -Command Get-ChildItem 
Cert:"CurrentUser\My\0B909E44056411513E2B22000705089445225" | Powershell -Command Remove-Item

cmdlet Remove-Item at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path[0]:
```

So is there any code that i can type in command so it will delete certificate
( name A  fingerprint 0B909E44056411513E2B22000705089445225)

Comment: Are you able to remove using the certificate manager?  If you can then your problem is a PowerShell syntax issue.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
gci cert:\CurrentUser\My\0B909E44056411513E2B22000705089445225 | foreach { Remove-Item $_.PSPath }
```

or from cmd / batch-file (just wrap the PowerShell command in `PowerShell -Command " "`)

```
PowerShell -Command "gci cert:\CurrentUser\My\0B909E44056411513E2B22000705089445225 | foreach { Remove-Item $_.PSPath }"
```

you can also look for the Certificate Name (FriendlyName) instead of the ThumbPrint:

```
gci cert:\CurrentUser\My | ? { $_.FriendlyName -eq 'A' } | foreach { Remove-Item $_.PSPath }
```

or even multiple Certificates with the `-in` operator (if you have PowerShell 3+)

```
gci cert:\CurrentUser\My | ? { $_.FriendlyName -in 'A','B','C' } | foreach { Remove-Item $_.PSPath }
```

first it searches for the certificate, loops over it and removes it.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed, using the FriendlyName.